# How can I reposition buttons on magento2 theme

Tags: magento2, ultimo

How can I change position of my buttons in magento theme I am using ultimo. I need something like this[image: To reposition after these buttons]
.Any help will be highly appreciated. AS I am so much stuck here

Comment: from where that Social Buttons are coming from? Is it coming from CMS block?

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal bro I installed ultimo theme , these are by default came with it.

Comment: Everyone is not using Ultimo theme so they are not aware  from its code. How it structured? That's why i asked you from where its coming?

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal actually I am very new in magento2 and I have to submit task. Not getting where to change things. If you could  tell me how to change things mean to say about files it would be great favor bro.

Comment: did you get solution for this ?